# Difference between "Having Said that" & "Despite of"

Tags: meaning, differences

I am not able to find out the difference between "Having said that" & "Despite of".

1. I like John as a person. Having said that, I don’t like his attitude.
2. I like John as a person despite my not liking his attitude.

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Comment: The second sentence is incorrect. "Despite of" should be followed by a noun phrase. You can also drop the "of" and follow it by an *ing verb. "despite (of), ..." is wrong in any case

Comment: 'Despite of' is not correct English. You could say either 'Despite that' or 'In spite of that' (where 'that' refers to the fact that you like John). 'Having said that' implies 'Even though I have just said that I like him', so thw sense is the same.

Comment: thank you. It would be great if i'll get more examples.

Comment: They are not related at all. "Having said that," merely notes that the fact has been mentioned just now. OTOH, "despite" (not "despite of") clearly implies that what you are now going to say goes against what has been said before.

Comment: You may also like to visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: Although they convey a **similar** meaning, the emphasis is different. In 1. meaning is *"and yet in contrast to what I have just said."* In 2. the idea is that you have set your opinion of his attitude aside for the purpose of saying that you like him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "having said that" and "despite" imply that what one is going to say next is in contrast or opposite to the previous statement.

Here is the Cambridge Dictionary [reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/having-said-that) for the same.